# How to exit the J console?

Tags: j

I recently downloaded j902 and can launch the console from my terminal, but I don't know how to exit. I tried “Ctrl + C” and "exit" but they did not work.

How do I exit the J console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ctrl+c signals break

ctrl+d exits

J verbs require an argument to run (otherwise they display). You need to provide an arg to exit.

exit 0

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Or you can type exit ''